# ASP.NET 5 Template crashes on first run

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm starting a new project in VS 2015.

File -> New -> Project -> ASP.NET Web Application -> ASP.NET 5 Templates -> Web API

A project is initialized. I would assume that if I run the project with IIS Express a service would be available.

It runs through the startup methods.

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => 
        WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

}

But then it crashes. I don't know how to implement global error handling.

I looked at [this example](https://github.com/filipw/apress-recipes-webapi/blob/master/Chapter%2007/7-3/Apress.Recipes.WebApi/Apress.Recipes.WebApi/NLogExceptionLogger.cs).

But when I try to use System.Net.Http or System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling they can't be found.

I also noticed that through intellisense it says Core 5.0 is no available.

Here is my project.json as requested.

```
{  
   "version":"1.0.0-*",
   "compilationOptions":{  
      "emitEntryPoint":true
   },
   "dependencies":{  
      "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler":"1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc":"6.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel":"1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles":"1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions":"1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json":"1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging":"1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console":"1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug":"1.0.0-rc1-final"
   },
   "commands":{  
      "web":"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
   },
   "frameworks":{  
      "dnx451":{  
         "frameworkAssemblies":{  
            "System.Web":"4.0.0.0"
         }
      },
      "dnxcore50":{  

      }
   },
   "exclude":[  
      "wwwroot",
      "node_modules"
   ],
   "publishExclude":[  
      "**.user",
      "**.vspscc"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your project.json please ? did you install `dnvm` ? And share the `dnu build` command output too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Visual Studio  Administrator Mode

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what is crashing - it's not clear from your description what crashes, when it crashes and how it crashes.

You can use `UseExceptionHandler` and `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` extension methods to configure an error handling page. This [article](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/diagnostics.html) describes it in more details.
If the exception happens during startup you may need to use `UseCaptureStartupErrors` extension method (it was recently [renamed](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/163) to `CaptureStartupErrors`).
Also, you already have logging enabled - the logs may also have some useful information. If you can't see logs because you log to the console consider logging to a file.

If this is IIS/IISExpress crashing check event log.

Comment: I like your idea, but I get a compiler error when I try using UseDeveloperExceptionPage or any of the others. It appears I am missing a dependency and I don't know how to diagnose that. VNext does dependencies different. I don't see a yellow exclamation.

Comment: I looked in the event log, but I didn't find anything. I ran the application and let it crash but nothing new showed up in the event log. I looked in all the folders for recent events.

Comment: To use UseDeveloperExceptionPage you need to take dependency on `Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics`

Answer (score 0):

What is your runtime version ?

Maybe you can try scaffolding your application with the [AspNet Yeoman generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnet) and compare the files. 
Personally I prefer to use the scaffolder as it is often up to date.

Hope this helps !